# Searching for PST Outlook data viewer

Tags: outlook

I need some **PST Viewer** to browse **emails** from and old **Outlook** 2007 backup. Just viewing and searching emails.
**What** could I use?

Open source solutions preferred. Free at least encouraged, if possible.
My version is 2007, but a multi-version solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be [Lookeen](https://lookeen.com/solutions/outlook-search/outlook-search.html)
While it isn't open source, it is based on open source [Lucene technology](https://lookeen.com/blog/lucene-strong-foundations-for-effective-search).
It will easily search your .pst files. Lookeen will also search the contents of your files and emails.

Lookeen is compatible with Windows 7.

It's free to use for 14 days.

(Full disclosure: I work for the developers of Lookeen)